# How can I concatenate a dataframe and a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Code:

```
df_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df_series = pd.Series([1,2,3,'N/A'],index = df_columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(df_series)
df
```

When I run the code above I receive the following output:

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  'N/A'
```

How can I write the code so that my Output is and df_columns is still the dataframe's index:

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  'N/A'
```

Comment: I think you need to just transpose the dataframe right? `df.T` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

So this would work, note the double brackets when loading in the data to designate the row.

```
import pandas as pd
df_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,'N/A']],columns= df_columns)
print(df)
```